# How do I match a string up to the first comma (if present) with a Ruby regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm struggling to get a regexp (in Ruby) that will provide the following

```
"one, two" -> "one"
"one, two, three" -> "one"
"one two three" -> "one two three"
```

I want to match any characters up until the first comma in a string. If there are no commas I want the entire string to be matched. My best effort so far is

```
/.*(?=,)?/
```

This produces the following output from the above examples

```
"one, two" -> "one"
"one, two, three" -> "one, two"
"one two three" -> "one two three"
```

Close but no cigar. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm wondering if it can't be simpler:

```
/([^,]+)/
```

Comment: Try `(.*?),` to find just in current line

Answer (score 15):

Does it *have* to be a regex? Another solution:

```
text.split(',').first
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be - but I 'want' it to be

Comment: Curious. Why do you 'want' it to be a regex? Is there an advantage?

Comment: @brad For what it's worth, you shouldn't get into the habit of thinking that all string problems require regexes. You can handle lots of cases in other ways.

Comment: I'd use `'text'.split(',').first` which avoids a regex entirely. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Would matching only non commas from the beginning work? e.g.:

```
/^[^,]+/
```

Comment: I had a similar idea. I think you need the parens for the capture, but I may steal your start-of-line anchor.

Comment: @Telemachus, you don't need parens in order for the whole regexp to match the required string.

Comment: @Telemachus, depends on how you use it, e.g.: string.match(/.../) would return anything that matches the regex or nil if nothing matched, no capture needed.  EDIT: What LarsH said.

Comment: @LarsH Maybe I'm confused, but without the parens, `$1` is not set (whether the regex matches the whole string or a sub-string).

Comment: @pbaumann Fair enough - I see now that he wasn't necessarily using `=~`.

Answer (score 2):

How about `/.*?(?=,|$)/` That way it either reads to the end or to a comma.

Comment: But if he does `/.*?(?=,)?/`, wouldn't that match the empty string?